# How can I locate what's causing postgres to consume so much cpu on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I ran `top` on my VM droplet and saw my postgres consuming a ridiculous amount of CPU in the background. I'm currently not running any queries.

[image]

How can I locate, given the information from the picture above, what's causing my postgres to act up. I see the PID and Command id's, wonderinf if I can use those to help me out.

Comment: Duplicate of [Mysterious postgres process pegging CPU at 100%; no running queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214824/mysterious-postgres-process-pegging-cpu-at-100-no-running-queries)

Comment: So is the only answer that I have been hacked?

Comment: Yes. Postgres never sets process names like that.

Comment: @AdamKG , do you have any recommenced steps I should take? Is it possible to boot him out?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, probably best to ask over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). All I can tell you is that wiping the machine definitely works :)